# What is the downside of TableAdapterManager?

Tags: c#, .net, tableadapter

I using tableAdapterManager for updating my data. But when i want save with this function the window is freezing. What do you about this problem?

Comment: This can be anything. The code, the hardware etc etc... We need more info to say anything usefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a BackgroundWorker to avoid your "window is freezing". Useful if you have lots of data to load.